# How to fetch values from dict

Tags: python, server-push

I am implementing a chat client gui whith **server-push functionality**. The messages that will be sent will look like this:

```
yourMessage = {'name': 'David', 'text': 'hello world'}
```

I recieve a server-push by a call to the **streamHandler**

```
def streamHandler(incomingData):
    if incomingData["event"] == "put":
        if incomingData["path"] == "/":
            if incomingData["data"] != None:
                for key in incomingData["data"]:
                    message = incomingData["data"][key]
                    handleMessage(message)
        else:
            message = incomingData["data"]
            handleMessage(message)
```

Then I have the function **handleMessage** that should retrieve the values of name and text:

```
def handleMessage(message):
    for key in message.values():
        printToMessages(key)
```

But now I get this Error: **'str' object has no attribute 'values'** I have tried making message to dict but with no success, any ideas?

Comment: As the error says, `message` is a string, not a dictionary.  How did you try "making message to dict"?

Comment: It appears the message is a stringified dict maybe? In that case you could `from ast import literal_eval as le` and `le(message)` to restore the dict from string.

Comment: I tried doing this: message: Dict(str, str) but then it says that it expects one argument not two. Then I tried one argument but that did not work either... @JohnGordon

Comment: `message` is a string.  Calling `dict()` on it is not going to magically fix your problem.

Comment: What does `message` (ie `incomingData["data"]`) look like? Can you do `print(message)` just before `handleMessage(message)` so that you see the data in it before the error message?

Comment: The message look like this when I print it: {'message': 'hello', 'name': 'jonathan'} @quamrana

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the `message` parameter is a `json` string.

If so you can have:

```
import json

def handleMessage(text):
    message = json.loads(text)
    for key in message.values():
        printToMessages(key)
```

Comment: I tried this, but then I got this error: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Comment: Well, your `text` variable is either a `dict` or a `str`. It can't be both. If it now seems to be a `dict`, then you don't need my modification.